# Roles in Django

Tags: django, permissions, roles, python-3.8, django-2.2

I'm creating web based system, where I have 5 or 6 different roles and access type. I made a research how to achieve this and everything is made only when create group in django admin and assign user into it but only from the administrative part. I need to create this from the views. I already have a form to add users with email and drop down menu to set the role type.

Any suggestions will be appreciated, because till now I don't have idea how to achieve this without to assign the users from django admin.

**my model.py for users:**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    ADMIN = 1
    RECEPTION = 2
    HEADOFDEPARTMENT = 3
    EMPLOYEE = 4
    PATIENT = 5
    NOTACTIVE = 6

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
        (RECEPTION, 'Reception'),
        (HEADOFDEPARTMENT, 'HeadOfDepartment'),
        (EMPLOYEE, 'Employee'),
        (PATIENT, 'Patient'),
        (NOTACTIVE, 'NotActive'),
      )
    role                            = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, blank=True, default=True, null=True)
    #email                           = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True) 
    username                        = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default='')
    is_superuser                    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin                        = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_employee                     = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_headofdepartment             = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_reception                    = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_patient                      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active                       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                        = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

def ViewFunc(request):
    ... #your func
    role = Group.objects.get(name='role') 
    role.user_set.add(user)
```

You retrieve the user object in the way you want in views, you add it in the user set in the group, done.

**EDIT**
Adding user `Foo` to `Admins` Group.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User


def ViewFunc(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username = 'Foo')
    role = Group.objects.get(name='Admins') 
    role.user_set.add(user)
```

Comment: Do I need to create the groups from the django admin panel first or just like how I did in my model in the question? These code should be in the model or in the views? name='role' role should be the field from the model right? Could you please explain more the code.

Comment: @pythondev You either create the group through admin or by code, this code should be in the view because i clearly said `ViewFunc` which is this view function you're going to write, and `role` is just a placeholder for the group name, you create a group called `Admins` or `Reception` and then retrieve it through `role = Group.objects.get(name='Admins')` then add the user.

Comment: This ViewFunc is not very clear to me what it is for. I thought I should add role = Group.objects.get(name='role') 
    role.user_set.add(user) to every function I want to restrict but as I got an error I think I didn't understand right

Comment: `ViewFunc` is a place holder, you write whatever you want in `views.py`, retrieve the user through forms or through url or in anyway you want, i will edit the answer to tell you how to retrieve it through username.

Comment: @pythondev edited the answer, you asked how to add users to groups, i answered, please edit your question if you have anymore questions.

Comment: Am I able to add it inside the model itself or close to it to add permission by groups?

Comment: @EliasPrado What do you mean by "add it inside the model itself" ?

Comment: I mean, I dont know where to add this function to automatically create the groups.